# issue with floating point when importing flat file comma separated SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, dataset, floating-point

I have an issue while importing this dataset.txt (flat file, comma separated)in SQL Server 2008

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,x21,x22,x23,x24,x25
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.645,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.351,2.332,2.643,1.698,1.687,1.698,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.445,0.431,0.444,0.440,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.648,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.637,2.332,2.649,1.695,1.687,1.695,1.720,1.744,0.592,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.443,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.625,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.637,2.334,2.643,1.696,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.446,0.429,1.0
0.437,0.501,3.625,3.626,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.353,2.334,2.642,1.730,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.593,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.444,0.429,1.0
0.438,0.498,3.626,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.640,2.334,2.639,1.696,1.687,1.695,1.717,1.744,0.592,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.449,0.431,0.444,0.441,0.429,1.0
0.439,0.498,3.626,3.629,5.000,2.918,5.000,2.633,2.334,2.645,1.705,1.686,1.694,1.719,1.744,0.589,0.502,0.493,0.504,0.446,0.431,0.444,0.444,0.430,1.0
0.440,5.000,3.627,3.628,5.000,2.919,3.028,2.346,2.330,2.638,1.727,1.684,1.692,1.714,1.745,0.588,0.501,0.492,0.504,0.451,0.433,0.446,0.444,0.432,1.0
0.444,5.021,3.631,3.634,5.000,2.919,5.000,2.626,2.327,2.638,1.698,1.680,1.688,1.709,1.740,0.595,0.500,0.491,0.503,0.453,0.436,0.448,0.444,0.436,1.0
0.451,5.025,3.635,3.639,5.000,2.920,3.027,2.620,2.323,2.632,1.706,1.673,1.681,1.703,0.753,0.595,0.499,0.491,0.502,0.457,0.440,0.453,0.454,0.442,2.0
0.458,5.022,3.640,3.644,5.000,2.922,5.000,2.346,2.321,2.628,1.688,1.666,1.674,1.696,0.744,0.590,0.496,0.490,0.498,0.462,0.444,0.458,0.461,0.449,2.0
0.465,0.525,3.646,3.670,5.000,2.923,5.000,2.611,2.315,2.631,1.674,1.658,1.666,1.688,0.735,0.593,0.495,0.488,0.497,0.467,0.449,0.462,0.469,0.457,2.0
0.473,0.533,3.652,3.676,5.000,2.925,5.000,2.607,2.310,2.623,1.669,1.651,1.659,1.684,0.729,0.578,0.496,0.487,0.498,0.469,0.454,0.467,0.476,0.465,2.0
0.481,0.544,3.658,3.678,5.000,2.926,5.000,2.606,2.303,2.619,1.668,1.643,1.651,1.275,0.723,0.581,0.495,0.486,0.497,0.477,0.459,0.472,0.484,0.472,2.0
0.484,0.544,3.661,3.665,5.000,2.928,5.000,2.321,2.304,5.022,1.647,1.639,1.646,1.270,0.757,0.623,0.493,0.484,0.495,0.480,0.461,0.474,0.485,0.476,2.0
0.484,0.532,3.669,3.662,2.945,2.926,5.000,2.326,2.306,2.620,1.648,1.639,1.646,1.270,0.760,0.533,0.493,0.483,0.494,0.507,0.461,0.473,0.486,0.476,2.0
0.482,0.520,3.685,3.664,2.952,2.927,5.000,2.981,2.307,2.329,1.650,1.640,1.644,1.268,0.757,0.533,0.492,0.482,0.492,0.513,0.459,0.474,0.485,0.474,2.0
0.481,0.522,3.682,3.661,2.955,2.927,2.957,2.984,1.700,2.622,1.651,1.641,1.645,1.272,0.761,0.530,0.492,0.482,0.492,0.513,0.462,0.486,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.480,0.525,3.694,3.664,2.948,2.926,2.950,2.995,1.697,2.619,1.651,1.642,1.646,1.269,0.762,0.530,0.493,0.482,0.492,0.516,0.462,0.486,0.483,0.473,2.0
0.481,0.515,5.018,3.664,2.956,2.927,2.947,2.993,1.697,2.622,1.651,1.641,1.645,1.269,0.765,0.592,0.489,0.482,0.495,0.531,0.462,0.499,0.483,0.473,2.0
```

I put the procedure I am following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So, if you can see, when selecting in SQL Server, the floating point desappears?
Maybe I am doing something wrong, in the column type, I also tried real, but get the same result, Do i have to tell something else to SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I did note is that you are doing something in Spanish not English. Do the Spanish use the , as the decimal separator (I know some countries do but don;t know which ones)?

Comment: Yeah, I am using spanish software, mmm `,` is not use as decimal separator, `.` is

Comment: @HLGEM: +1 this is a possibility

Comment: I have tried, decimal, but get the same result, What else could I do

Comment: @cMinor: Would you mind trying with the default values for locale and codepage? And why would you need to set the locale different from defaults, with your current data structure in this file?

Comment: Ok, I will do it, mmm, I was asked to do this

Answer (score 0):

In Advance options, could you set dataprecision/datascale and try it again? That might help. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Change regional settings to USA and ensure decimal places . or ,
Change country too and select USA.
Restart SQL Server Management and try it.
It works for me in Spain!